# What happens if a Jewish king marries a 19th wife?

Tags: marriage, reward-punishment, malchut-royalty, maseches-sanhedrin, kiddushin-eirusin

The mishna on [Sanhedrin 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21a.3?lang=bi) teaches us that a king may not have more than 18 wives, and this is also codified by The Rambam ([Hilchos Malachim 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.3.2?lang=bi&with=Sanhedrin&lang2=bi)):

> לֹא יַרְבֶּה לוֹ נָשִׁים. מִפִּי הַשְּׁמוּעָה לָמְדוּ שֶׁהוּא לוֹקֵחַ עַד שְׁמוֹנֶה עֶשְׂרֵה נָשִׁים בֵּין הַנָּשִׁים וּפִלַּגְשִׁים **הַכּל שְׁמוֹנֶה עֶשְׂרֵה**
>
> "He must not have too many women" (Deut. 17:17). By Tradition we have learned that he may have **up to eighteen women** including wives and concubines.

Now if a king were to marry a 19th wife:

- Would we say the kiddushin isn't valid?
- If it is valid, do we make him divorce her?
- Does the king get a punishment?

Comment: Before someone posts this as a partial answer: Yes, מלך לא דן ולא דנין לו. However, that’s only Rabbinic, as a result of the incident with Shimon Ben Shetach’s court attempting to judge King Yannai. On a Torah level (or even a Rabbinic one before Shimon Ben Shetach), however, this question still stands.

Comment: @DonielF Not only that, but that rule applies only to מלכי ישראל.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rambam, Hilchos Melachim 3:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14918):

> ואם הוסיף אחת ובעלה לוקה
>
> If he adds an extra wife and has relations with her, he gets lashed.

So that answers question #3. As for the others:

1. On the face of it, kiddushin ought to take effect like in any other case of חייבי לאוין (according to everyone except R' Akiva, and maybe even according to him, since the issur isn't really on marrying her as an individual, just as wife #19). Although [Minchas Chinuch 501](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=37518#p=140&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) understands the Chinuch to be saying that the issur is violated already when the kiddushin is done, and in that case that maybe it doesn't take effect, under the rule כל דאמר רחמנא לא תעביד אי עביד לא מהני.
2. Would he have to divorce her? Probably, since otherwise he's continuing to do the aveirah. Minchas Chinuch there says she'd need a get because of the safek above, whether the kiddushin took effect.

In a comment on the OP, @heshy asked whether she'd become a chalalah (or rather, a zonah). Minchas Chinuch there says no, because it's not an איסור השוה בכל.

Comment: Could he divorce a different wife instead?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Rambam says there יש לו לגרש ולישא אחרת תחת זו שגירש. So it would seem that yes, he could.

Comment: @doubleaa "Kiymu velo kiymu" if they warn him to divorce and he chooses not to in front of Eidim he gets Malkus Makkos 15b Meir is correct

Comment: @user15464 By the time he's done kiddushin and had relations with wife #19, it's too late for him to get out of malkus by divorcing her (or any of the others), no? It's not a לאו הניתק לעשה.

Comment: @doubleaa he can only get a Malkus with a forewarning so i guess they warn him not to have relations as the Rambam says, so youre right that remaining married alone cannot make him chayav Malkus in which case not a Lav Hanitak Lease to get divorced. But note the Kesef Mishna thinks that being married alone is the prohibition without relations so according to him it would be a Lav hanitak leasei "ל מנא לן שצריך שיבעלנה דילמא כשקדשה לבד מיקרי מרבה

Comment: Interesting that the Rambam writes ובעלה. Why isn’t Kiddushin enough to be in violation?

Comment: @DonielF Maybe because he draws an analogy with the Kohen Godol, who is also chayav only if he does kiddushin and has relations.

Comment: @user15464 I'm still not sure that even according to the Kesef Mishna it would be a לאו הניתק לעשה, since the posuk doesn't order him to divorce her (so it's not like ולא תותירו... באש תשרופו or לא תקח... שלח תשלח).

Comment: @meir Lav hanitak leasei is an impediment that can mean that there are no Malkus if there is a takana like giving back a stolen item. When you warn him to divorce and he refuses this is trangressing the lav of lo yarbe lo nashim when he refuses and is chayav malkus because of Kiymu velo kiymu and there is no impediment of Lav Hanitak leasei any more. See Makkos 15b.

Comment: @user15464 But in all the examples the Gemara brings there, this isn't one of them. So it sounds like once he's done kiddushin and be'ilah, he's getting malkus, whether he divorces her afterwards or not (unlike the motzi shem ra who divorces his wife, where if he remarries her there's no malkus). And if he refuses to divorce - that's a לאו שאין בו מעשה at that point, no?